# Post data as an array in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm implementing an API using Django Rest framework. I wonder Python can send POST params as an array like Ruby does?

For example:

```
POST /api/end_point/
params = { 'user_id': [1,2,3] }

# In controller, we get an array of user_id:
user_ids = params[:user_id] # [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of ways to deal with this in `django-rest-framework`, depending on what you are actually trying to do.

If you are planning on passing this data through `POST` data then you should use a `Serializer`. Using a serializer and `django-rest-framework`s `Serializer` you can provide the `POST` data through `json` or through a `form`.

`Serializer` documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/
`Serializer Field` documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/

Specifically you will want to look at the `ListField`.

It's not tested, but you will want something along the lines of:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

class ItemSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Your Custom Serializer"""
    # Gets a list of Integers
    user_ids = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField())

@api_view(['POST'])
def item_list(request):
    item_serializer = ItemSerializer(data=request.data)
    item_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user_ids = item_serializer.data['user_ids']
    # etc ...
```