# Post LIST OF OBJECTS from HTML/axios with multipart/form-data to DRF multipart parser

Tags: html, django, api, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data

This is my serializer:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = ChildSerializer(many=True)  # reverse FK relation
```

`ParentSerializer` also has an image field, so the request has to be multipart/form-data to support both image and data in a single request.

The following code/test works fine:

```
test_data = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
dictionary = {
    'name': ['test'],
    'children[0]': [{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}]
}
test_data.update(MultiValueDict(dictionary))

test_serializer = self.get_serializer(data=test_data)
test_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
test_instance = test_serializer.save()
```

...because I'm manually creating the `children` list.

The problem is I'm not able to do the same through axios/HTML form. The data being sent is converted to string.

What are my options? I want to send list of child objects along with other data.

`DRF v3.9` & `Django v2.2`.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960870/post-data-as-an-array-in-django-rest-framework?

Comment: add `ChildSerializer` and `viewset/view`, error traceback if any.

Comment: Please post your request. It is very likely that the request body (i.e. name of fields) is not appropriate for DRF. Also post any errors that you get.

Comment: I've implemented a workaround for now, but I expect it to work with field names like `field_name[0][key_one]` `field_name[0][key_two]` `field_name[1][key_one]` and so on... DRF/MultipartParser is able to detect that there are multiple `field_name` fields, but not able to detect keys in the array, i.e. `key_one` & `key_two`, and throwing error that both these fields are required (or nothing in case fields are optional, but doesn't register those values).

Comment: Please note that I'm referring to `MultipartParser` not `JSONParser`. JSON is straight-forward, but in `multipart/form-data`, the values being sent with each key *has* to be string. So I can't send JSON like `{"field_name": [{"key": "value", "key2": "value"}, {"key": "value2"...}...]}` because that becomes `[Object Object]` in the request as it can't parse anything except string.

Comment: your field names should be of the form `children[0]key1`, `children[0]key2`, `children[1]key1`, `children[1]key2`

Comment: Note that there is no dot `.` between the `]` and the key name

Comment: I believe I've tried that, but let me give it another try and share the exact issue here.

Comment: @ivissani That worked! Thanks. You may post this as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your fields must be named in the following form `children[0]key1`, `children[0]key2`, `children[1]key1`, `children[1]key2`

Note that there is no dot `.` between the `]` and the key name

Comment: This is definitely worth a blog post as it is the first reference I could find on handling POSTing of lists of complex objects to DRF using multipart!